# How to parse an html string based on certain delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

`#202020#<font face="Helvetica">this is string entered by a # user #202021# </font><b style=""><font face="Helvetica Neue" style="">#<u>001</u>10#&nbsp;</font></b>`

Expected result:
`#202020#<font face="Helvetica">this is string entered by a # user #202021# </font><b style=""><font face="Helvetica Neue" style="">#00110#<u></u>&nbsp;</font></b>`

Given an html string like the above, I want to be able to rearrange characters delimited by '#'s and the 5 digit numbers included between them.

Right now I have been trying to use regex to strip the html and then split based on '#', but it doesn't work because there could be a '#' that isn't a part of my '#' markdown. I also don't know how to recombine my split arrays of string chunks, hmtl tags, and '#' number chunks. It doesn't matter if I strip or move out the styling on the '#12345#' part of the string, as long as those characters are grouped, so they cna be moved or wrapped around the hash markdown arbitrarily.

The reason for the above is that I have a wysiwyg component that has a requirement to store this '#12345#' formatted markdown, where on the server this is converted to a url based on a lookup table. On save I want to be able to format the '#' markdown. The wysiwyg editor I'm using is react-summernote.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry just added an example expected result. Doesn't matter how I format the markdown itself so it can be wrapped by the tags that were between the markdown or can be prepended like in my example.

Comment: Is the only requirement to output `#00110#<u></u>` from input `#<u>001</u>10#`? Why are there space characters in tag names?

Comment: The wysiwyg editor allows people to just arbitrarily select any part of their string including between the hashes, resulting in auto-inserted HTML tags mangling the '#12345#' formatting on save.

And yes! I need to output what you just described.

Comment: How is the first string at the question created?

Comment: It is the result of summernote wysiwyg editor.  We allow users to denote a '#12345#' to indicate that the server should convert this part of the HTML string to a url, but on the client side users can arbitrarily style this string after writing '#12345#'.  Sometimes they will only select part of this hash delimited markdown resulting in HTML tags being inserted between the hashes.

Comment: How do you determine what the user is expecting?

Comment: We don't care about HTML tags that format the '#12345#' markdown, so we can just strip them out or move them.  The rest of the string should stay as is with styling.  Basically the only thing that can mangle the '#12345#' markdown is insertion of HTML tags inside it, and there's no way to prevent the user from doing so.

Comment: What is the difference between `# user #202021#` and `#202021#`? If your rule is : "Pick five digits between two consecutive `#`s and ignore anything else", then there is no difference between the two. You need to disallow some characters inside your target string. Then the problem will reduce to traversing the string once and identify the pattern. If the pattern is simple, you might not even need regex.

Comment: @jrook Unfortunately we are not allowed to disallow characters, and so I'm stuck with a problem that may perhaps be solved by building a sort of abstract syntax tree or similar.  I don't want to go overengineer a solution for such a small use-case but yes.  I understand if we disallow using `#` for anything other than this markdown formatting rule of `#12345#`, then it's just a matter of finding the pattern :(

Comment: ASTs will not solve your problem if you cannot even tokenize the string without ambiguity. If `#` marks the start and end of the pattern, then extra `#`s either need to be disallowed or escaped; otherwise you can remove `abcd#` from`#abcd#12345#` or remove nothing and both will be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `string.replace`, a regex and a callback.
The regex

```
/#([^#]*\d)#/g
```

looks for two `#` enclosing numbers and anything which is not a `#`.

In the callback, you remove all non-digit characters, and count the remaining numbers. If there are five numbers, you return the numbers enclosed in `#`, otherwise, you do nothing, you just return the original tag.

You can also use positive lookahead and lookbehinds to not capture the `#`, in which case you won't need to include the hashes when replacing the tag

```
/(?<=#)([^#]*\d)(?=#)/g
```

```js
const func = str => str.replace(/(?<=#)([^#]*\d)(?=#)/g, (a, tag) => {
  const numbers = tag.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove non-digits
  if (numbers.length === 5) {
    return numbers; // return the numbers part of the tag
  }
  return tag; // return tag untouched
});

console.log(func('#12<b>345</b>6#'));
console.log(func('#1<b>2</b>34#'));
console.log(func('#12345#'));
console.log(func('#1<b>234</b>5#'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me #00110#. I also need the entire HTML string back, not just the codes between the '#' markdown.

Comment: @user11110267, I udpated the answer to return the whole tag, does it help?

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, I don't need the URL to be created on the client side, a server that I don't have access to handles that piece.  I just need to be able to save as #12345# format in the string.  Also, it still cannot handle when the hash markdown has HTML tags in between the markdown delimiter '#'.

Comment: @user11110267, I see, I misunderstood the question, I updated the answer, it now works with mangled tags